# Lottie (4.1) animations not displaying on Android and potentially iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, lottie

I know this question has been asked before in another thread - [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75490938/lottie-animation-not-showing-for-xamarin-ios-app)

However, I wanted to ask if anyone has a solution to this problem, I have installed Lottie 4.1 to my PCL project and the animation, at least on Android, is not rendering.

Xaml:

```
<lottie:AnimationView
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
Animation="lottie_loading.json"
AnimationSource="AssetOrBundle"
HeightRequest="50"
WidthRequest="50"
RepeatMode="Restart" />
```

The file in the Android's project resources directory:

[File in Android Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEyM3.png)

`lottie_loading.json` properties:

[File properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IriJP.png)

All the other answers I have found have been older versions of Lottie stating the `AnimationViewRenderer` needs to be initialised with `AnimationViewRenderer.Init()` - however the method `Init()` no longer exists and I've read some answers on other posts that state you no longer need to install the package to both iOS and Android projects.

I have tried adding the respective packages to the appropriate projects and spent time researching the issue to see if am missing something.

I was expecting this to work out the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research and working on the problem, I discovered that if I changed the asset type on Android to `AndroidAsset`, move the JSON file to the `Assets` folder in the Android project and set the repeat mode to `Infinite` - it loaded.

Whether or not the issue occurs on iOS, I'm not yet sure, but I'll edit my answer if it does and I solve the problem.

Hopefully this helps someone